# Single function that handle multiple QObjects

Tags: qt, function

Hi I have a problem, in my program I have several QLabel and QTextbrowser, at times, I want each of them to display something, but I want to do this through another function called NewMessage. So NewMessage will receive message from QLabel or QTextbrowser, and process them, then display it. But the problem is I don't want to have overloading function for QLabel and QTextBrowser, I want only 1 NewMessage function that can handle message pass in by either QLabel or QTextBrowser(the objects have to pass themselves in as well), how should I do that? Does it has to do with something called casting? Thank you !

Comment: What do you mean by "NewMessage will receive message from QLabel or QTextBrowser" ? Will `NewMessage` be connected to signals emited by `QLabel` or `QTextBrowser` ? Is `NewMessage` displaying something ?

Comment: yea, NewMessage is displaying whatever the object need to display, like a function to handle the display job, and of course to process other stuff. I am not sure how to passed in both different object (QLabel and QTextBrowser), maybe emit signal is a good idea, but how do I display thing in the UI using the object then? For example, maybe in somewhere a QLabel object call labelABC emit a signal,in the slot NewMessage maybe I would do sender()->objectName, and I can get the name labelABC. but I wan to do something like labelABC->setText("..."), how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understand what you want to achieve.  May be you could start by reading Qt documentation about QObject and qobject_cast :

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#qobject_cast